# How can I flip a CALayer with CATransform3D?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Looking for help on how to have a CALayer flip like a UIView using CATransform3D.

I have seen some articles but I'm  having a hard time understanding the 4D and 3D coordinates system, model and references. I also read apple's documentation, but I'm not understanding it either.

My goal is to flip a card located within a layer within a view. I know I could use uiview to do the same thing, but i would rather use a calayer

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Drew McCormack provides code for just such an animation [here](http://www.mentalfaculty.com/mentalfaculty/Blog/Entries/2010/9/22_FLIPPIN_OUT_AT_NSVIEW.html), based on previous work by Mike Lee.  While he bases his flipping around an NSView, the actual animation is performed on a CALayer generated from the contents of the view.  The few view-related components of his implementation can be replaced by pure layers in your case.

Comment: Seems that the site you provided is down.

Comment: @Ole - He's having issues with his hosting provider right now.  Try back a little later.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
let moveTransform = scaleTransform.translatedBy(x: -yourViewWidth, y: 0)
let transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(moveTransform)
yourView.wantsLayer = true
yourView.layer?.sublayerTransform = transform
```